# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects there is no Generate option

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

I got a strage problem I've download the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects""in order to generate a SetUp project, in my notebook all works fine , but when another programer downloads the project from VisualStudio On line,  there is no way to generate the setup. 
When I right clic the setup project on my notebook  I can see the Generate option and the setup is generated, but in other notebook  there is no way to generate the installer because there is no generate option as you can see in the image below

[image: there is no generate option]

what can I do ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Well it's localized, so it'll be Compiler, corresponding to the first item on the English context menu for the setup project, which is Build.

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean, the problem is the localization?

Comment: Your settings are in different languages or in different preferences. On my VS 2015 the top two choices are Build and Rebuild. The menu shown in your post is not all English - for example you have Cambiar nombre where I have rename. So you apparently have a mixture of Visual Studio or .NET language packs or Installer project versions mixed up together with maybe a language setting in your OS.  You have Spanish items on that menu, that's why you have no Generate or Build or Rebuild or Rename.

Comment: yes you are right,... but how Can I fix this? any Idea?

Comment: Surely it's that Compiler choice at the top, yes?

Comment: yes it is just like  the pic, and as you can see  there is no "Generate" menu item,... so I can not generate an installer

Comment: Have you tried Compiler? Honestly, as I said before, you seem to have Spanish menu items in your VS, so why aren't you complaining that there is no Delete, Rename, Properties when Eliminar, Cambiar nombre, Propiedadas are exactly the same in Spanish?